# how to automate report sending in sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, automation

in app script how to automate a range of sheet should be snapshot and send through email or any other social apps
i have a sheet which changes data every day and i need to send that snap of data every day to my boss how i can automate this please help me

i want this automation in app script

Comment: Please add more context, ie. tool names, env. existing things you see.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MailApp class. Check out the documentation for SendEmail() here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailmessage

Here is a sample script that you can use:

```js
function sendData() {
  var emailAddress = 'email@mail.com';
  var subject = 'Data';
  var message = 'Here is the data';

  var attachmentName = 'data.xlsx';
  var fileId = "insert your spreadsheet ID here";
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + fileId + "&exportFormat=xlsx",
    {
      "headers": {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
      "muteHttpExceptions": true
    }
  ).getBlob().setName(attachmentName);
  var optAdvancedArgs = {name: attachmentName, attachments: [data] };

  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, optAdvancedArgs);
}
```